# web page looks bad in chrome when downloading

Tags: css, google-chrome

when I download this page:

https://botoxparty.github.io/XP.css/

it looks bad in google chrome.
it seems that it deactivates the css if the page is opened offline.

is there any way to view the css files or resources offline?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is a GitHub repository where you can see the project in its entirity. Just download the source code from the repository using the Download Zip button on the top right

[image]

and the code can be found under the `gui` folder

https://github.com/botoxparty/XP.css

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use [HTTrack](https://www.httrack.com/) to download and save it